# Looking for a systematically flattening function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I kind of feel stupid asking this, but I can't figure it out.

What I'm looking for is a function that incrementally flattens out at specific points.

y = x/100 is fine for the first 10 y, but after that a single point of y will require 200 points.

Then at y = 20 the rate increases again to 300 x per y. At 30 it increases to 400, at 40 to 500, etc.

[image]

Technically what I'm looking for is a step function that increments only when the threshold is reached, but I can take care of that afterwards using rounding.

[image]

What sort of function would have behaviour like this?

Comment: Try $f(x) = 100\left \lceil{ \frac{x}{10}}\right \rceil $ where the brackets denote the ceiling function.

Comment: Have you considered a logarithmic function?

Comment: Thank you @MattiP. that is an accurate formula for the increasing rate. I was able to use that to resolve my problem using some spreadsheet shenanigans (using the previous value in the series).